# Is it possible to prevent having multiple selectors when setting an event listener on a button with an image inside?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image inside a button, and I want to listen to clicks on the button.
Since the listener is on the button, then when the click is done on the `img`, it won't work:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches(".my-button")) {
    console.log('My button clicked')
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 1em;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
  background-color: #4681f4;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">
  <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/483/483054.png" width="40" height="40"/>
</button>
```

So I have to add a second selector for the inner `img` as well:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches(".my-button, .my-button img")) {
    console.log('My button clicked')
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: none;
  padding: 1em;
  font: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: inherit;
  background-color: #4681f4;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">
  <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/483/483054.png" width="40" height="40"/>
</button>
```

But that feels redundant and as if I am doing something wrong.
Is there a way to avoid this? I was thinking at first to just use the `img` without a `button` element, but that feels like not according to the spec.

Comment: Use [`.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) instead of `.matches`.

Comment: @Teemu thanks. So the syntax is simply `if (event.target.closest(".my-button")) ..`? No need "equals to something"  i.e.  `if (event.target.closest(".my-button")) === ..`?

Comment: No need for any further checking, `closest` returns `null` (a falsy value), if a matching element is not found, then the condition is not passed. An element would be a truthy value, then the condition is passed.

Comment: Got it! Then I am using this instead. Thank you

Comment: `element.closest(selector)` checks and returns the element if it matches the selector, or checks nodes in the parent chain of the element if it doesn't match the selector itself. No equality check required, its operands are the element it called on, and the selector argument supplied.

Comment: Is there a reason you bind the event listener to the document and not to the button itself, therefore eliminating the need for a selector condition in the first place?

Comment: @TiKay I have a table with hundreds of rows, each row has buttons. I don't want to set a listener to each button because that would probably stuck the page or make it very slow, so I use delegation and set a single listener on the document (I could set it on the table or any of the closest static elements, but that didn't matter for me in this case)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `e.target` you can find your button with `document.querySelector`

```js
document.querySelector('.my-button').onclick = () => {
   console.log('clicked');
}
```

that way it'll also detect when you interact with any of the button's children